# My foundation-based menu doesn't display on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, zurb-foundation

I'm using Fundation to build my website, I found an interesting code on the net and adapted it to my needs. It now woks very well on chrome/Safari but simply doesn't display on firefox. Any clue ?

Here is my HTML :

```
<!-- NAV BAR -->
        <div class="row show-for-large-up">
            <div class="mega-menu">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul class="left">
                            <!-- Menu 1 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-dropdown="menu-1" data-options="is_hover:true" >
                                    <strong>Catégorie 1</strong>
                                </a>
                                <div id="menu-1" data-dropdown-content="" class="large f-dropdown content row">
                                        <!-- Heading 1 -->  
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="large-3 columns">
                                                <img src="images/enfants.png" height="265px" width="265px" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="large-9 columns">
                                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                                <h3>Enfants</h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>  
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat-button">
                                                    <a href="#" class="button large alert round right">Découvrir</a>
                                                </div>      
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <!-- Menu 2 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-dropdown="menu-2" data-options="is_hover:true">
                                    <strong>Catégorie 2</strong>
                                </a>
                                <div id="menu-2" data-dropdown-content="" class="large f-dropdown content row">
                                        <!-- Heading 1 -->  
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="large-3 columns" style="margin-top:1.5%;">
                                                <img src="images/enfants.png" height="265px" width="265px" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="large-9 columns">
                                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                                <h3>Bijoux</h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>  
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat-button">
                                                    <a href="#" class="button large alert round right">Découvrir</a>
                                                </div>      
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <!-- Menu 3 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-dropdown="menu-3" data-options="is_hover:true">
                                    <strong>Catégorie 3</strong>
                                </a>
                                <div id="menu-3" data-dropdown-content="" class="large f-dropdown content row">
                                        <!-- Heading 1 -->  
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="large-3 columns">
                                                <img src="images/enfants.png" height="265px" width="265px" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="large-9 columns">
                                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                                <h3>Maison</h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat">
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 1</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 2</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 3</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 4</a><br>
                                                            <a href="#">Sous-catégorie 5</a><br>
                                                </div>  
                                                <div class="large-4 columns subcat-button">
                                                    <a href="#" class="button large alert round right">Découvrir</a>
                                                </div>      
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <li class="spacer"></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="right l_nav-input">
                            <li class="has-form">
                                <div class="row collapse">
                                    <div class="large-10 medium-10 columns l_nav-input">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-2 medium-2 columns">
                                    <a href="#"><p class="magnifier"><i class="foundicon-search size-21"></i></p></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here the CSS (SCSS notation):

```
.mega-menu .open {
    border-top: none;
    border-color: #CCC;
    background: #EBEAEA;
    left: 0 !important;
}

.mega-menu .f-dropdown:before,
            .mega-menu .f-dropdown:after {
                border-style: none;
            }

#menu-1{
    .row{
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color:#FB6E06;
        background-color:#EBEAEA;
        margin:-15px -20px -15px -20px; 
        border-right-style:none; 
        border-left-style:none;

        .large-3{
            margin-top:1.5%;

            img{
                margin-top:0; 
                margin-left:0; 
                margin-right:0;
            }
        }

        .large-9{
            margin-top:-5px;

            .large-12{
                h3{
                    font-family: Paprika; 
                    margin-top:15px;
                }
            }

            .subcat{
                text-align:left;
                a{
                    background-color:#EBEAEA;
                    color:#5d5459;
                }
            }

            .subcat-button{
                margin-top: 26%;
            }
        }
    }
}

#menu-2{
    .row{
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color:#FB6E06;
        background-color:#EBEAEA;
        margin:-15px -20px -15px -20px; 
        border-right-style:none; 
        border-left-style:none;

        .large-3{
            margin-top:1.5%;

            img{
                margin-top:0; 
                margin-left:0; 
                margin-right:0;
            }
        }

        .large-9{
            margin-top:-5px;

            .large-12{
                h3{
                    font-family: Paprika; 
                    margin-top:15px;
                }
            }

            .subcat{
                text-align:left;
                a{
                    background-color:#EBEAEA;
                    color:#5d5459;
                }
            }

            .subcat-button{
                margin-top: 26%;
            }
        }
    }
}

#menu-3{
    .row{
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color:#FB6E06;
        background-color:#EBEAEA;
        margin:-15px -20px -15px -20px; 
        border-right-style:none; 
        border-left-style:none;

        .large-3{
            margin-top:1.5%;

            img{
                margin-top:0; 
                margin-left:0; 
                margin-right:0;
            }
        }

        .large-9{
            margin-top:-5px;

            .large-12{
                h3{
                    font-family: Paprika; 
                    margin-top:15px;
                }
            }

            .subcat{
                text-align:left;
                a{
                    background-color:#EBEAEA;
                    color:#5d5459;
                }
            }

            .subcat-button{
                margin-top: 26%;
            }
        }
    }
}

.foundicon-search{
    float: left;
}

.magnifier{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    color: $c_orange;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: you really reasigned margins and everything for each menu point again? Foundation is doing all this really nicely for you.. and you likely have broken something on the way. Since i wont refactor your code for you, i just guess that your firefox window is too small to meet the condition of the media query for "show-for-large-up"

Comment: @NicoO I feel completely dumb not to have thought about it, sincerely. Thanks for the margin advice, I'll optimize all this later on. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you very welcome. And don't worry too much, we all have been there ;)